# Keep properly space between column in awk (width of each field)?

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a huge problem. I am working on .gro files, which looks like that:

```
    1BGL     C5    1   2.636  14.120   1.951 -0.0345 -0.8088 -0.2809
    1BGL     H5    2   2.573  14.031   1.945  0.1969 -1.0999  1.1792
    1BGL     O5    3   2.567  14.198   1.847 -1.0918 -0.2789 -0.0370
    1BGL     C1    4   2.644  14.307   1.793 -0.3029 -0.4378 -0.4234
    1BGL     H1    5   2.600  14.360   1.709  1.4710  0.2783 -0.9469
    1BGL     C2    6   2.794  14.277   1.750  0.2264  0.3957  0.6673
    1BGL     H2    7   2.855  14.363   1.723  0.7219  0.1907  1.1240
    1BGL     O2    8   2.787  14.184   1.640 -0.1728 -0.5002 -0.0302
    1BGL    HO2    9   2.788  14.247   1.569  1.3442 -0.4575  0.0054
    1BGL     C3   10   2.868  14.205   1.867  0.4088  0.4514  0.0495
    1BGL     H3   11   2.962  14.157   1.840  0.0154 -2.1311  2.8580
    1BGL     O3   12   2.901  14.298   1.973  0.0978  0.1123 -0.2596
    1BGL    HO3   13   2.942  14.246   2.040 -1.2865  3.4404  3.5009
    1BGL     C4   14   2.783  14.089   1.918  0.6092  0.5852 -0.0412
    1BGL     H4   15   2.786  14.021   1.832  0.7162 -0.0675  0.4699
    1BGL     O4   16   2.854  14.040   2.031  0.3832 -0.0763 -0.6561
```

When I use awk, it looks like

```
1BGL C5 1 2.636 14.120 1.951 -0.0345 -0.8088 -0.2809
1BGL H5 2 2.573 14.031 1.945 0.1969 -1.0999 1.1792
1BGL O5 3 2.567 14.198 1.847 -1.0918 -0.2789 -0.0370
1BGL C1 4 2.644 14.307 1.793 -0.3029 -0.4378 -0.4234
1BGL H1 5 2.600 14.360 1.709 1.4710 0.2783 -0.9469
1BGL C2 6 2.794 14.277 1.750 0.2264 0.3957 0.6673
1BGL H2 7 2.855 14.363 1.723 0.7219 0.1907 1.1240
1BGL O2 8 2.787 14.184 1.640 -0.1728 -0.5002 -0.0302
1BGL HO2 9 2.788 14.247 1.569 1.3442 -0.4575 0.0054
1BGL C3 10 2.868 14.205 1.867 0.4088 0.4514 0.0495
1BGL H3 11 2.962 14.157 1.840 0.0154 -2.1311 2.8580
1BGL O3 12 2.901 14.298 1.973 0.0978 0.1123 -0.2596
1BGL HO3 13 2.942 14.246 2.040 -1.2865 3.4404 3.5009
1BGL C4 14 2.783 14.089 1.918 0.6092 0.5852 -0.0412
1BGL H4 15 2.786 14.021 1.832 0.7162 -0.0675 0.4699
1BGL O4 16 2.854 14.040 2.031 0.3832 -0.0763 -0.6561
```

You can read about it here 
http://manual.gromacs.org/archive/5.0.4/online/gro.html

This format is fixed, ie. all columns are in a fixed position. Optionally (for now only yet with trjconv) you can write gro files with any number of decimal places, the format will then be n+5 positions with n decimal places (n+1 for velocities) in stead of 8 with 3 (with 4 for velocities). Upon reading, the precision will be inferred from the distance between the decimal points (which will be n+5). Columns contain the following information (from left to right):

```
residue number (5 positions, integer)
residue name (5 characters)
atom name (5 characters)
atom number (5 positions, integer)
position (in nm, x y z in 3 columns, each 8 positions with 3 decimal places)
velocity (in nm/ps (or km/s), x y z in 3 columns, each 8 positions with 4 decimal places)
```

Note that separate molecules or ions (e.g. water or Cl-) are regarded as residues. If you want to write such a file in your own program without using the GROMACS libraries you can use the following formats:

C format
    "%5d%-5s%5s%5d%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.4f%8.4f%8.4f"

So I want to keep properly space between columns after I use awk. Is it possible to do that like in C using for example printf("%8i %6 i", column1, column2)?

For example I use that script

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
FNR==1{
  ++count
  value=count"BGL"
}
{
  $1=value
}
1
FNR%3==0{
  ++count
  value=count"BGL"
}
' after_SOL.gro | tee after_SOL2.gro
```

Fragment of my input

```
    1BGL     C5    1   2.636  14.120   1.951 -0.0345 -0.8088 -0.2809
    1BGL     H5    2   2.573  14.031   1.945  0.1969 -1.0999  1.1792
    1BGL     O5    3   2.567  14.198   1.847 -1.0918 -0.2789 -0.0370
    1BGL     C5  130   6.603  15.918   1.894 -0.6780  0.4970 -0.5245
    1BGL     H5  131   6.632  15.913   1.999  0.6027 -3.0418 -0.9360
    1BGL     O5  132   6.497  16.023   1.909 -1.1935  0.9474 -0.2080
    1BGL     C5  259   5.066   8.182   0.249 -0.2465 -0.7831 -0.0006
    1BGL     H5  260   5.085   8.166   0.355  2.0262 -0.0662 -0.2570
    1BGL     O5  261   5.080   8.322   0.226 -0.6550 -0.0725 -0.0582
```

And my output

```
1BGL C5 1 2.636 14.120 1.951 -0.0345 -0.8088 -0.2809
1BGL H5 2 2.573 14.031 1.945 0.1969 -1.0999 1.1792
1BGL O5 3 2.567 14.198 1.847 -1.0918 -0.2789 -0.0370
2BGL C5 130 6.603 15.918 1.894 -0.6780 0.4970 -0.5245
2BGL H5 131 6.632 15.913 1.999 0.6027 -3.0418 -0.9360
2BGL O5 132 6.497 16.023 1.909 -1.1935 0.9474 -0.2080
3BGL C5 259 5.066 8.182 0.249 -0.2465 -0.7831 -0.0006
3BGL H5 260 5.085 8.166 0.355 2.0262 -0.0662 -0.2570
3BGL O5 261 5.080 8.322 0.226 -0.6550 -0.0725 -0.0582
```

No its not possible to use that file in GROMACS program, because it needs properly space between column

Comment: Yes, have you tried? If so, what awk command did you execute and in what way did it fail? What is it you're trying to do to your input to produce different output, I don't see any difference in any of the values? If we're supposed to infer something about the transformation from statements like `Note that separate molecules or ions (e.g. water or Cl-) are regarded as residues` then YMMV.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for answer I edit and put one of my script.

Comment: Values is different in the first column for me the spacee between column is important. Too keep them. For example here:
```
    1BGL     O5
```
You have 4 white space then 1BGL then 5 white space then O5.

Here you have:
```
3BGL O5
```
3BGL one white space and O5. I want to have 4 white space then 3BGL then 5 white space then O5.

Comment: Don't try to show formatted text in a comment and anything we need to know, put in your question. is it **really** the space between columns you want to preserve or is it actually the width of each field?

Comment: Width of each field for sure, because I have different lengths of number in my file.

Comment: The script you posted doesn't produce the output you posted when run against the input you posted. Please fix your question to show us sample input, the expected output given that input, the script you ran and want help with, and the incorrect output that script produces when run against the input you posted. Again, just keep it simple for us and you stand the best chance of getting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you posted doesn't produce the output you posted but if it did then here's what you'd change it to:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1{
  ++count
  value=count"BGL"
}
{
  match($0,/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+/)
  $0 = sprintf("%*s%s",RLENGTH,value,substr($0,RLENGTH+1))
}
1
FNR%22==0{
  ++count
  value=count"BGL"
}
```

Here's how I'd really write the script you're using though to get the output you posted so you're not writing duplicate code to increment `count` and set `value` and you don't need `count` or `value` variables anyway:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    match($0,/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+/)
    printf "%*d%s\n", RLENGTH, int(((NR-1)/3)+1), substr($0,RLENGTH+1)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
    1BGL     C5    1   2.636  14.120   1.951 -0.0345 -0.8088 -0.2809
    1BGL     H5    2   2.573  14.031   1.945  0.1969 -1.0999  1.1792
    1BGL     O5    3   2.567  14.198   1.847 -1.0918 -0.2789 -0.0370
    2BGL     C5  130   6.603  15.918   1.894 -0.6780  0.4970 -0.5245
    2BGL     H5  131   6.632  15.913   1.999  0.6027 -3.0418 -0.9360
    2BGL     O5  132   6.497  16.023   1.909 -1.1935  0.9474 -0.2080
    3BGL     C5  259   5.066   8.182   0.249 -0.2465 -0.7831 -0.0006
    3BGL     H5  260   5.085   8.166   0.355  2.0262 -0.0662 -0.2570
    3BGL     O5  261   5.080   8.322   0.226 -0.6550 -0.0725 -0.0582
```

Comment: You're welcome but you should usually wait a few hours before accepting an answer to see what answers you get as the first answer you get won't always be the best one. Looking back at your previous questions - you would probably have got better answers to them if you had waited.